# Unique date range fields in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table that consists of, among other things, two fields named StartTime and EndTime. Both are TIME fields.

I want to add a constraint preventing the insertion of any records that overlap with preexisting time ranges. E.g. if a record already exists with StartTime = 5:00, EndTime = 10:00, I would want an insert with StartTime = 6:00, EndTime = 9:00 to fail due to the overlap.

Is there any way to accomplish this, with or without triggers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The trigger below should work - it is also possible to do this with check contraints, but the logic shown in [this post](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/alexander_kuznetsov/archive/2009/03/08/storing-intervals-of-time-with-no-overlaps.aspx) kind of hurts my head.

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[DateRangeTrigger]
   ON  [dbo].[TargetTable]
   FOR INSERT, UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN

IF EXISTS (SELECT t.starttime, t.endtime FROM TargetTable t
        Join inserted i
        On (i.starttime > t.starttime AND i.starttime < t.endtime AND i.UniqueId <> t.UniqueId) 
           OR (i.endtime < t.endtime AND i.endtime > t.starttime AND i.UniqueId <> t.UniqueId)
           OR (i.starttime < t.starttime AND i.endtime > t.endtime AND i.UniqueId <> t.UniqueId)
        )
BEGIN
    RAISERROR ('Inserted date was within invalid range', 16, 1)
    IF (@@TRANCOUNT>0)
        ROLLBACK
END


END
```

Comment: Whoops, one more question. Won't this only work for insert? You capture update also in the trigger, but I only see a case handling insertion.

Comment: Hmmmm - looking at this, I don't think the update case is possible without including some primary key to leverage. I've updated my answer with that.

Comment: There's a problem in the join condition; "i.endtime < t.endtime AND i.endtime > t.endtime" will always evaluate to false.

Comment: Thanks whatsit - fixed that up now.

Comment: Just added the final (that I can think of) required clause, to cover the total overlap case in the new record.

Comment: To prevent exactly the same time range being inserted multiple times I think the checks should be changed to >= and <=.

Answer (score 4):

I haven't tried it but I imagine something like this would work:

```
create trigger preventOverlaps
on infotable
FOR Insert, Update
As
DECLARE @Count int;
select @Count = count(*) from infotable where 
  (inserted.startdate > startDate && inserted.startdate < endDate) ||
  (inserted.endDate < endDate && inserted.endDate > startDate)
if(@Count > 0)
begin
   rollback transaction;
end
```

Comment: +1 from me - somehow when I first tested this the FOR didn't seem to work correctly. Later when checking that, it worked fine. I'm leaving my answer just to have the t-sql syntax on the && and ||.

Comment: You miss the case where one time range completely encompasses the other - as David Hall's answer shows you need one additional check in your logic.

Answer (score 2):

This trigger will also work for situations where one timespan completely contains the other. For example, if there's an existing record for 6:00 - 9:00 and you try to insert one for 5:00 - 10:00.
(Based on David Hall's answer)

```
CREATE TRIGGER DateRangeOverlapTrigger
ON  TargetTable
FOR INSERT, UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
IF EXISTS
    (SELECT t.UniqueId
    FROM TargetTable t
        JOIN inserted i ON i.starttime < t.endtime
            AND i.endtime > t.starttime
            AND i.UniqueId <> t.UniqueId)
BEGIN
    RAISERROR ('Invalid due to time overlap', 16, 1)
    IF (@@TRANCOUNT > 0)
        ROLLBACK
END
END
```

Comment: This trigger only works for instances that ONLY contain one another, not a partial overlap. Some combination of the two answers is needed.

Comment: @bytenik: I can't see what the problem is. Can you give a specific example that the trigger won't work for?