# Check for Overlapping date on Insert/Update

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table which holds a list of dates and more data for a person. The table should never have any undeleted overlapping rows (Dates overlapping).

Is there a way I can put a check constraint on the table, to ensure that when I update or insert a row, that there's no overlapping details?

Below is a cut down version of my table. It has a deleted flag, and start/end dates. A 'Null' end date means it's ongoing.

I then provide some legal, and some not-so-legal inserts (and why they're legal and illegal).

```
DECLARE @Test TABLE
(
    Id INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1),
    PersonID INT NOT NULL,
    StartDate DATE NOT NULL,
    EndDate DATE NULL,
    Deleted BIT NOT NULL
)


INSERT INTO @Test
(PersonId, StartDate, EndDate, Deleted)
SELECT 1, '01-JAN-2015', '15-JAN-2015', 0 UNION ALL -- Valid
SELECT 1, '16-JAN-2015', '20-JAN-2015', 1 UNION ALL -- Valid and deleted
SELECT 1, '18-JAN-2015', NULL, 0 UNION ALL -- Valid
SELECT 2, '01-JAN-2015', NULL, 0 UNION ALL -- Valid.. never ending row.
SELECT 2, '18-JAN-2015', '30-JAN-2015', 0 UNION ALL -- Invalid! Overlaps above record.
SELECT 2, '20-JAN-2015', '30-JAN-2015', 1 UNION ALL -- Valid, as it's deleted (Still overlaps, though)
SELECT 3, '01-JAN-2015', '10-JAN-2015', 0 UNION ALL -- Valid
SELECT 3, '10-JAN-2015', NULL, 0 -- Invalid, as it overlaps the last and first days

SELECT * FROM @Test
```

I need to make sure that the table doesn't allow overlapping dates for the same person, for undeleted rows.

For the date range check, I will use the "(StartA <= EndB)  and  (EndA >= StartB)" formula, but unsure how to check this with a constraint, and across multiple rows.

I may need to do it with a Trigger, by checking the inserted.values to the exiting, and somehow, cancel if I find matches?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you cannot use a `CHECK` Constraint without adding [additional columns](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/alexander_kuznetsov/archive/2009/03/08/storing-intervals-of-time-with-no-overlaps.aspx). 
you will have to create a `Trigger` to check if inserted date ranges are non overlapping. Something like this..

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[DateRangeTrigger]
   ON  [dbo].Test AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
DECLARE @MaxDate DATE = '2999/12/31'
    IF EXISTS (SELECT t.StartDate, t.EndDate FROM Test t
            Join inserted i
            On i.PersonID = t.PersonID
            AND i.id <> t.Id
            AND(
                 (i.StartDate > t.StartDate AND i.StartDate < ISNULL(t.EndDate,@MaxDate))
                OR (ISNULL(i.EndDate,@MaxDate) < ISNULL(t.EndDate,@MaxDate) AND ISNULL(i.EndDate,@MaxDate) > t.StartDate)
                OR (i.StartDate < t.StartDate AND ISNULL(i.EndDate,@MaxDate) > ISNULL(t.EndDate,@MaxDate))
               )
            WHERE t.Deleted = 0 AND i.Deleted = 0
            )
    BEGIN
        RAISERROR ('Inserted date was within invalid range', 16, 1)
        IF (@@TRANCOUNT>0)
            ROLLBACK
    END

END
```

You can refer to one of these threads for more information

[Enforcing unique date range fields in SQL Server 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16567922/enforcing-unique-date-range-fields-in-sql-server-2008)

[Unique date range fields in SQL Server 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1898858/unique-date-range-fields-in-sql-server-2008)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a trigger-based approach:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[trigPersonnel_PreventOverlaps]
   ON  [dbo].[Personnel] 
   AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN

    IF EXISTS(
        SELECT * FROM DateRange p 
        INNER JOIN inserted i ON i.PersonID = p.PersonID 
                AND i.Id != p.Id AND i.Deleted = 0
        AND (
            (p.StartDate <= i.StartDate 
                AND (i.StartDate <= p.EndDate OR p.EndDate IS NULL))
            OR (p.StartDate <= i.EndDate 
                AND (i.EndDate <= p.EndDate OR p.EndDate IS NULL))
        )
        WHERE p.Deleted = 0
    )
    --RAISEERROR if you want
    ROLLBACK
END
```

Note - it will roll back the whole transaction, so you'll need to perform inserts individually to ensure good ones don't get thrown out.
If you need something to comb through a bulk insert and pick out the bad ones, you'll need something more complex.